# visual tool to resolve conflicts merged into a single file

Tags: merge, diff

I did a git merge and ended up with a file like that looks like this:

```
class member extends item{
    /********CONSTANTS**********/ 
    const is_flaggable = true;
    const is_commentable = false;
    const is_ratable = false; 
    const table = 'member'; 
<<<<<<< HEAD
    const table_about = 'mem_about' ;
    const table_to_about  = 'mem_to_about' ;
    const table_hobbies = 'mem_to_hobby'; 

=======
    const table_friendship = 'friendship'; 
    const table_about = 'mem_about' ;
    const table_to_about  = 'mem_to_about' ;
    const table_hobbies = 'mem_to_hobby'; 
    const table_friendship_id = 3; 
>>>>>>> my-copy
```

In this file there are many blocks like this.  Is there a visual tool to help me look at this file and pick and choose the changes I want?  Most of the diff tools I found are for looking at two files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows you can use [CVS Conflict Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/conflicteditor/).  On Linux use [TKDiff](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tkdiff/)'s `-conflict <filename>` switch.